# Multiple classes mean ROC calculation

Tags: python, object-detection, roc

Let's suppose I've got (for simplicity) 3 class object detector and I would like to plot mean ROC curve. I can successfully plot ROC for each class, as shown below.

[image: ROC]

Values are correct and so curves are. Problem is that I've got (as you can see on the plot) different count of samples for each class.

For example (random data):

```
Class 31
FPR :['0.00', '0.20', '0.30']
TPR :['0.00', '0.20', '0.30']

Class 39
FPR :['0.00', '0.20', '0.30', '0.40', '0.50']
TPR :['0.00', '0.20', '0.30', '0.40', '0.50']

Class 42
FPR :['0.00', '0.20', '0.30', '0.40', '0.50', '0.60', '0.70', '0.80']
TPR :['0.00', '0.20', '0.30', '0.40', '0.50', '0.60', '0.70', '0.80']
```

---

I am using [this script](https://github.com/Cartucho/mAP/blob/master/main.py) for evaluation (recall/sensitivity is already calculated as you can see on the line [647](https://github.com/Cartucho/mAP/blob/master/main.py#L647)) and I've slightly modified it to compute also FPR (1-specificity) as following:

```
fpr = tp[:]
for idx, val in enumerate(tp):
    fpr[idx] = float(fp[idx]) / (fp[idx] + (gt_counter_per_class[class_name] - tp[idx]))
```

and plotting the ROC (recall vs 1-specificity) as following

```
plt.plot(fpr, rec, label='ROC curve of the class {0} (AUC = {1:0.2f})'
         ''.format(class_name, auc(fpr, rec)))
```

---

I have already spent hours on this but can not figure out how to calculate mean ROC from multiple ROC curves (for each class) if there is **different count** of samples for each class. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You want to do vertical averaging as described by Fawcett: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/data/roc/fawcett-roc.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using interpolation for each class separately

```
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tps))
```

and then compute the mean values

```
mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)

plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='k',
     label='Mean ROC (AUC = {0:0.2f})'.format(mean_auc))
```

and result looks like this

[image]